# Is this a valid Singleton in C# 6

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I was making this to implement a singleton pattern

```
private static ProcessDao _dao;
public static ProcessDao Dao
{
    get { return _dao ?? (_dao = new ProcessDao()); }
}
```

but in C# 6 auto properties has default values.
Is this a correct implementation of singleton?

```
public static ProcessDao Dao { get; } = new ProcessDao();
```

Comment: @OrelEraki Unless the type has *other* static members (virtually no singletons ever will) then it's as lazy as it needs to be.

Comment: The first snippet you have is unquestionably not thread safe; multiple objects can be created.  You should not have been using that in earlier versions.

Comment: [csharpindepth about singletons in c#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) is always a good read.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a correct implementation of singleton?

Your first example is wrong in the sense that it isn't a thread-safe implementation of a singleton. If multiple threads called `ProcessDao.Instance`, you're likely to see different instances of the private field being created.

In contrary to that, your second example *is thread-safe*, as the compiler actually translates your auto-implemented getter only property to:

```
public class ProcessDao
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static readonly ProcessDao <Dao>k__BackingField;
    public static ProcessDao Dao
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return ProcessDao.<Dao>k__BackingField;
        }
    }
    static ProcessDao()
    {
        ProcessDao.<Dao>k__BackingField = new ProcessDao();
    }
}
```

The static constructor invocation is guaranteed by the runtime to at most once, so you're also getting the guarantee that this will not create multiple instances of the backing field.

Regarding laziness, that depends on the implementation of your `ProcessDao` class. The static constructor is guaranteed to run before the first reference of a static field in the class. If you have multiple static fields exposed, then the first will cause the invocation and the allocation of these objects. If you know you'll be using other static members and want maximum laziness, look into the [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) type introduced in .NET 4.0.